# Where do I start if I want to customise the WxPython rich text control?

Tags: python, wxpython, richtext

Does anyone know of any articles or code samples to get me started customising the WxPython rich text control?

I am trying to extend the rich text control to allow me to insert controls (buttons, text boxes etc) into the editing area e.g. instead of just inserting images or formatted text I would like to be able to insert a control such as a button (similar to the output provided by the HTML controls but I need to provide an editable interface).

Looking through the documentation for wxpython and wxWidgets it seems there is the infrastructure built into the controls to support this but I cannot find any help or examples to get me started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the wxpython demo from their site, it should provide you with an in-depth example of a wxRichTextCtrl. Without providing any information about your specific customizations, there is not much else I can help with.

Comment: Thanks. I already have the wxpython demo and have looked at the source code for the wxRichTextCtrl which only shows you how to use the standard formatting features. I will edit my question to make my requirements clearer.